# To which object this keyword refers inside lambda expression?

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, this

I know that in Java the **this** keyword inside lambda expression refers to the instance of the class that enclosed the lambda expression.
But I am not sure how does it work in Kotlin if argument function type doesn't include a receiver?
If it includes a receiver so *this* keyword refers to the receiver, but what if it isn't include a receiver? Is in this situation **this** keyword is invalid?

Comment: It refers to whatever `this` would be in the next scope out.

Comment: @Tenfour04, sorry i can't understand you. When trying to use 'this' keyword, let say when using **let** function with a lambda expression, and writing the word *this* inside the bracket, i'm getting the next error: *'this'is not defined in this context*

Comment: @Eitanos30, that error answers your question: in that situation, the `this` keyword is invalid.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, ok thank you mate

Comment: If the lambda has a receiver, i.e. defined as `A.(params) -> returntype` then `A` will be the `this` there, and you can access outer `this` using the [qualified this expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html). Otherwise `this` is this of outer scope.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu, what do you mean outer scope? It looks invalid

Comment: @Eitanos30 outer scope is any class (or function in the class) it is created under.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu, thank you. My problem was that i was "under" main function.

Comment: There is no `this` defined there, only classes has `this` variable pointing to their current reference :) Lambdas are not exactly SAM conversions in Kotlin, lambdas can be inlined as well using `inline` modifier etc.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu, and if the lambda is inline, does it mean you can't use *this* keyword inside the lambda expression?

Comment: `this` keyword is never defined for lambdas regardless they are inlined or not (it was just an example). `this` is only defined for receiver lambdas. Why would there be a need of this keyword if it does not have any property, and just invocation is required to run that via `()`?